# Howto protect an ANT task / target from accidental execution?

Tags: eclipse, ant

I have written an ANT script which deployes an application to my local development Java EE enviroment. I need the same function to deploy it to the productive enviroment.

I often only want to deploy to the development server and rarely to the productive one. I'm using Eclipse IDE. Depending on the way ANT is used, it could happen, that I accidantally deploy to the productive server, with just one wrong click.

What is the best way, to build this functionality that way, that I could not deploy accedantally to the producte system?

- Two separate ANT scripts?
- Twoseparate ANT targets?
- Is there any password protection for
  ANT tasks or targets?
- Any other way?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe first add for some extra input, so you have to click and press enter?
Since ant 1.7, there is an [input task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/input.html)

Answer (score 1):

Require a property to be set for the production deploy, and then only deploy to production from the command line (with -DreallyDeployToProduction=true or whatever).

Answer (score 0):

I vote for separate Ant scripts.